# How to set item centered horizontally and vertically in android?

Tags: android, gravity

how can i how can I make it centered verrically and horizontally at the same time?

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Comment: -1 for the poor grammar, typos, and vagueness of the question. What "item" are you referring to? Using mbaird's solution will work if you want your particular widget (e.g. TextView, ImageView) to be centered within the parent layout. Using `android:gravity` rather than `android:layout_gravity` will cause the content of the widget to be centered WITHIN the widget.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, set `android:layout_gravity="center"`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity